# Delete rows where id is same as in other table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ok, here's the deal:
I have following two tables in MySql-database:

```
**custwishes**
userid
wishid

**coursewishes**
wishid
coursename
wishmonth
```

"custwishes.userid" references to users-table, and custwishes.wishid is same as "coursewishes.wishid".

Now I would like to delete all records from coursewishes, where coursewishes.wishid=custwishes.wishid AND custwishes.userid=?.

I can do this with php, collecting all the necessary id's and making the delete-query in a loop for those id's, but that doesn't seem like a good idea.

I didn't even know what kind of title I should put for this question, so I hope it's not too misleading.

Any help would appreciated!

**Update 07082014:13:28**

I tried the "Ende Neu"'s method, but no luck. The suggestion deletes from custwishes, not from coursewishes like I would like it to do. I tried this modified version:

```
    DELETE
    FROM coursewishes
    WHERE coursewishes.wishid 
    IN (
      SELECT wishid 
      FROM custwishes
    )
    AND custwishes.userid = 5
```

This obviously results in error, because system cannot find custwishes.userid.

Perhaps there is a way to use JOIN or something alike? I'll have it a go and post what happens.

**Update 11082014:12:01**

Returned to the problem today, and I managed to get the cascading to work. Problem was, that I had the cascade made wrong way. :) Meaning that it cascaded from coursewishes to custwishes, not the other way around like it was supposed to.

Comment: You can use foreign keys to autodelete associated rows

Comment: I cannot get the foreign key-trick to work. It works when I delete the user, and it deletes also the lines of "custwishes", but it doesn't cascade to the "coursewishes"-table.

Comment: When you delete `custwishes`, cascade to `coursewishes`, not from `user` table

Comment: Sorry, having difficulties delivering the message here.. :) What you suggested, is what I'm doing. I meant that I have two cascades, one from users to custwishes, and it works, and other from custwishes to coursewishes, but it doesn't work. <-- Meaning that it doesn't delete the rows in coursewishes.

Comment: I wonder if there's any other information that could be provided that might be pertinent to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JOIN in DELETE statement.

If you only want to delete from coursewishes, use this statement

```
DELETE coursewishes
FROM coursewishes
JOIN custwishes ON coursewishes.wishid = custwishes.wishid 
WHERE custwishes.userid = 5;
```

If you want to delete from both tables, use

```
DELETE coursewishes, custwishes
FROM coursewishes
JOIN custwishes ON coursewishes.wishid = custwishes.wishid 
WHERE custwishes.userid = 5;
```

ON DELETE cascade works in one direction only.